# How to modify URLs in Yii2

Tags: yii, yii2, friendly-url

I have this URL:

> blog/74/title-news

But I want URL without ID:

> blog/title-news

My rules look like this:

```
'rules' => [
    'blog/<id>/<title>' => 'blog/details/',
],
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Please post your BlogController as well.

Comment: I guess if you delete ID, in the controller you will have a problem

Answer (score 0):

If you need this only for URL of one news, you can simply solve this by [`UrlManager::$rules` config](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/runtime-routing#default-parameter-values):

```
'rules' => [
    [
        'pattern' => 'blog/<id:\d+>/title-news',
        'route' => 'blog/details',
        'defaults' => ['id' => 74, 'title' => 'title-news'],
    ],
    // ...other rules...
]
```

This will change URL for news with ID `74`.

If you need to do this for all URLs, first you need to make sure that all your `title`s used in URLs are unique. Then configure rules:

```
'rules' => [
    'blog/<title>' => 'blog/details',
]
```

And remove `id` param when you create URL for news - it should look like this:

```
Url::to(['blog/details', 'title' => $model->title]);
```